# Why read fails with cqlsh query when huge tombstones is present

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a table with huge tombstones.So when i performed a spark job (which reads) on that specific table, it gave result without any issues. But i executed same query using cqlsh it gave me error because huge tombstones present in that table.

> Cassandra failure during read query at consistency one(1 replica
>   needed but o replicas responded ,1 failed

I know tombstones should not be there, i can run repair to avoid them , but apart from that why spark succeeded and cqlsh failed. They both use same sessions and queries.

How `spark-cassandra` connector works? is it different than cqlsh?
Please let me know .

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spark Cassandra Connector is different to cqlsh in a few ways.

- It uses the Java Driver and not the python Driver
- It has significantly more lenient retry policies
- It full table scans by breaking the request up into pieces

Any of these items could be contributing to why it would work in SCC and not in CQLSH.